# Excel IF AND function to calculate date

Tags: excel

I am writing a formula to the first day from dates formatted in Quarter and Year

For example Q1-2014, 
The range is Q1-2014 to Q4 2015 .

I have stripped out the data into two new column

For example: Q1- 2014 -   Q1 and 2014

I am writing this formula to get the first date of the Q1 - 2014

> =IF(AND(J6="Q1",(D6=2014)),41640,(IF(AND(J6="Q2",(D6=2014)),41730),(IF(AND(J6="Q3",(D6=2014)),41913,(IF(AND(J6="Q4",(D6=2014)),42005,(IF(AND(J6="Q1",(D6=2015)),42095,(IF(AND(J6="Q2",(D6=2015)),42186,(IF(AND(J6="Q3",(D6=2015)),42278,"Error"))))))))))))

For Q1 2014 it works - Output is 1-Jan-2014 
It gives error Q2 2014 and beyond

Thanks your your help in advance

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=DATE(B1,(RIGHT(A1)-1)*3+1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=DATE(B1,CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1,1),1,4,7,9),1)`

[image]